# Android Background Process during Idle

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I understood the implementation of AsyncTask. What I want to achieve is to add background process when the app is not active or the user is idle. Is that possible? I need to download some bulk amount of data over slower internet connection for this reason I want my process to run background.

Please suggest something.

Comment: I think using a **Service** is appropriate for this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I want to achieve is to add background process when the app is not active or the user is idle. Is that possible?

There is no real concept in Android of "user is idle".

> I need to download some bulk amount of data over slower internet connection for this reason I want my process to run background.

Use an `IntentService`.

Comment: I have implemented the IntentService. Now I have an issue. I want to know in a particular activity if the download has been completed as I will be using data that are being downloaded in the activity. If not downloaded I want to show the user ProgressDialog. And if downloaded user can easily use it. How can I do this?

Comment: @Debopam: A `ProgressDialog` can only be raised by an activity, and you may not have an activity in the foreground. So you have three cases: "a particular activity" is in the foreground, some other activity of yours is in the foreground, and *no* activity of yours is in the foreground. The latter case is ideal for a `Notification`. See http://commonsware.com/blog/2010/08/11/activity-notification-ordered-broadcast.html and https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Notifications/Ordered

Comment: Let me describe it a little further. I have five Activity class. Activity 1 starts my service. I want my data to be ready by Activity 5. But if due to poor connectivity or slow network. If my user comes to Activity 5 and if the intent service is still updating then I want my activity to show progress dialog or disable all the components until and unless my download successfully completes.

Comment: @Debopam: Then Activity 5 needs to examine the environment to see if the work is completed, and if not, it can listen for a broadcast to be sent by the service. In that case, though, you could use `LocalBroadcastManager` from the Android Support package, for a bit better speed and security: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Intents/Local